# Adding up values in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a JavaScript array of data, which currently looks like this

```
2021-09-01 00:10:00,11,10,'John',23
2021-09-01 13:20:00,12,20,'Sarah',55
2021-09-01 18:50:00,34,5,'Garry',12
2021-09-02 09:01:00,22,40,'Vicki',53
2021-09-02 14:23:00,34,2,'Peter',123
2021-09-02 16:20:00,21,10,'Victor',03
2021-09-02 18:00:00,88,40,'Nelly',3
```

You will notice that the first part is a date, for example "2021-09-01 00:10:00"

How can I create a new javascript array from that data which groups the rows by date, so in my example it would be 2 rows

```
2021-09-01
2021-09-02
```

And then add up the 3rd comma-separated value of each row (the values just before the persons name), so in my example it would output

```
2021-09-01,35
2021-09-02,92
```

And then give a total number of rows found for each group (there are 3 rows for 2021-09-01 and 4 rows for 2021-09-02)

```
2021-09-01,35,3
2021-09-02,92,4
```

Then return an average for each row (for example, first row = 35 / 3 = 11.66)

```
2021-09-01,35,3,11.66
2021-09-02,92,4,23
```

I then want to do a bit of maths on each row, but hopefully I can figure that out

Is this at all possible?

This would be a big help if anyone has an idea

Thank you

==================

WOW thank you everyone for your suggestions, maybe I was a little confused by saying it was an array, but when I did a console.log of my "sampledata" data, it was showing it as array

I'm basically using this, and want to run my original question on the sampledata output

```
d3.queue()
.defer(d3.csv, "test.csv")
.await(function(error, sampledata)
{
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(sampledata);       
});
```

if this helps

Comment: That's not an array. Maybe it's an array of arrays. Please put your data in proper code syntax so we know what we're looking at.

Comment: You have CSV tagged, but then talk about arrays in your description and make no mention of CSVs...

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @RyanIs, please elaborate on  `I have a JavaScript array of data, which currently looks like this`  - I see strings of CSV which is what you tagged. If indeed CSV, then my code should work

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for your help so far, sorry im a little new to this, I added a little bit more info to my answer on what i'm doing and why I thought it was an array. I'm using d3 as I have a few csv I want to load at once

Comment: So did my answer help?

Comment: @mplungjan yep with a few tweaks it worked well, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like reduce for this

```js
const csv = `2021-09-01 00:10:00,11,10,'John',23
2021-09-01 13:20:00,12,20,'Sarah',55
2021-09-01 18:50:00,34,5,'Garry',12
2021-09-02 09:01:00,22,40,'Vicki',53
2021-09-02 14:23:00,34,2,'Peter',123
2021-09-02 16:20:00,21,10,'Victor',03
2021-09-02 18:00:00,88,40,'Nelly',3`;

const arr = csv.split("\n"); // split the csv on newline
const res = arr.reduce((acc,cur) => { 
  let [date,ignore,num] = cur.split(","); // regex is needed if there are quoted commas before the interesting data
  date = date.split(" ")[0]; // take the date part
  acc[date] = acc[date] || {sum:0,cnt:0, avg:0 }; // reuse if existing, create new if not
  acc[date].sum += +num; 
  acc[date].cnt++;
  acc[date].avg = +(acc[date].sum/acc[date].cnt).toFixed(2); // remove decimals more than 2
  return acc
},{})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work since OP has an array of data, not a csv string. Of course it can be converted, but it's not as trivial as just calling one function...

Comment: I believe OP has a CSV as tagged and has possibly converted it to an array. AND it IS an array after I do `csv.split("\n");`

Comment: But it's an array with a different shape than the one OP has...

Comment: I LITERALLY copied and pasted OP's lines into a template literal - what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to create an object to map dates to their respective values, then, you'll iterate over your array in groups of 5.

```js
const itemsByDate = {};

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i += 5) {
  const date = items[i].toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  const value = items[i + 2];
  
  if (!itemsByDate[date]) {
    itemsByDate[date] = {
      value,
      count: 1
    }
  }
  else {
    itemsByDate[date].value += value;
    itemsByDate[date].count += 1;
  }
}
```

Then you iterate over the values of itemsByDate and calculate the average

```js
for (const item of Object.values(itemsByDate)) {
  item.mean = item.value / item.count;
}
```

If you really want to restructure your data as an array again, which I don't think is a good idea if you want to treat that data with javascript, you can do that with

```js
const myArray = Object.entries(itemsByDate).flatMap(([date, item]) => {
  return [date, item.value, item.count, item.mean];
});
```

Comment: The date is not a date object. It is a string. No need to use date manipulation on it

Comment: If you click `[<>]` in the editor and you can make a [mcve]

Comment: Just strip the toISOString() part and it should work fine. It's intendend only to convert the date to a string.

Comment: It is not my question. I just advice you since you have more code than OP needs

Comment: Where is YOUR array? OP's rows are not a JS array. They are just 7 strings

Comment: Just read the actual code posted. OP might not know what an array is. What he posted is NOT an array and even if it was, item[0] is NOT a date, but a string. IF it had been an array, that string should ALSO have been quoted

Comment: This is how to represent an array: `[["2021-09-01 00:10:00",11,10,"John",23],
["2021-09-01 13:20:00",12,20,"Sarah",55]...]` in which case your code would fail.
ALTERNATIVELY: `["2021-09-01 00:10:00",11,10,"John",23,"2021-09-01 13:20:00",12,20,"Sarah",55 ...]` in which case your code would ALSO fail

Comment: Ok... So, the author specifically says he has a "JavaScript array" and wants "a new javascript array" but I must assume he's just wrong about that and has a string instead... Nice...

Comment: And, since the date is not quoted, I assumed it is indeed a date... I think maybe it's just better just to ask the author in the comments...

Comment: Alexander did an hour ago... No answer so far.